# Sails js with socket io: how to subscribe to new Model that fits criteria, during onCreate?

Tags: sockets, model, socket.io

I am using Sails js 0.11.

Following the tutorial described on the docs [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub):

I am able to create a pub/sub relationship. However I only want to be notified of "update" events of users that have the field "company=abc". Therefore in the controller I do the following:

```
subscribe: function(req, res) {
    User.find({company:'abc"}).exec(function(e,listOfUsers){
      User.subscribe(req.socket,listOfUsers,['create','destroy']);
    });
}
```

This works. However in the case this socket is open, and a new user belonging to this company is created, the socket won't receive notifications for this new user.

In order to solve that, I went to User model, and added:

```
beforeCreate: function(user, next) {

 //just need one sample of user from this company.
 //in theory all users of this company are subscribed by same sockets
 User.findOne({company:user.company}).exec(function(e,companyUser){

    // Get all of the sockets that are subscribed to this user
    var subscribers = User.subscribers(companyUser);

    // Subscribe them all to this new user
    _.each(subscribers, function(subscriber) {
      User.subscribe(subscriber.id, user);
    });
     next();
 });
```

}

However I get the warning

```
warn: `Model.subscribe()` called by a non-socket request. Only requests originating from a connected socket may be subscribed. Ignoring...
```

I do not want to create user using sockets. Is there a way around this? Just want to keep my socket subscribers up to date!

Thanks

Comment: turns out there were two errors with the above. It should be User.subscribe(subscriber, user);, and I should have called it on Model.afterCreate. However my sockets arent being notified, even if I do a User.publishCreate({id: user.id, user:user});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, putting this in the afterCreate won't really work because the subscriber would receive the message when the object created, but you are putting this after its being created so the event won't run.

However with a trick, we can make this work. Subscribe to the Company instead of the User, here are the details:

So first, subscribe your user to it's company (owner is the company id in my sails app):

```
Company.findOne({id: req.session.user.owner}).exec(function(e, company) {
    Company.subscribe(req.socket, company);
});
```

Then when you create a User, in the afterCreate, look for the company id in your socket message. Retrieve all of the subscribers of that company, and subscribe them to the "message" context of a User model. Then right after you subscribed all of your user's send a "message" type message to them via the Company model's message() function.

```
  afterCreate: function(message, next) {
    Company.findOne({id: message.owner}).exec(function(e, company) {
        var subscribers = Company.subscribers(company);
        _.each(subscribers, function(subscriber) {
            User.subscribe(subscriber, message, 'message');
        });

        Company.message(company, message.message);
    });

    next();
  },
```

Here, the message object is the socket.io payload.  In the first section where you subscribe your socket client to the company, you can have criteria to specify which user's to subscribe to where, even you can create a specific subscribers criteria table where you store all the different subscription channels.

Hope it helps.

References:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/subscribe

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/message

Comment: Thank you, that was a creative way to solve it. In the end I just used sails.sockets.join and sails.sockets.broadcast.... I believe working with rooms is much better, because using the sockets associated with models sometimes can cause issues since model creation/update is assynchronous. Anyway, I wrote about this in my blog: http://impacta.us/sails-with-socket-io-part-24/

Comment: In the line `User.subscribe(subscriber, message, 'message');` I can't find that third parameter in the documentation (`message`), can you link me or explain what it does? thx @ZoltanSzabo