# How to specify criteria when using model.subscribe

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I am trying to use the model.subscribe to subscribe socket clients to specific events:
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/subscribe

But is there any way to subscribe a socket client to only created items with a specific criteria?

For example I have a Message model:
Attributes:
-type
-owner
-message
-id
-createdAt
-updatedAt

Is there any way to subscribe only Messages created with owner 1 or 2?

I tried this:

```
Message.find({owner: 1}).exec(function(e, messages){
    Message.subscribe(req.socket, messages, ['create']);
});
```

In the log I received something like:

```
2015.07.06 16:05:29 SILLY Subscribed to the Message with id=3 (room :: sails_model_message_3:create)
2015.07.06 16:05:29 SILLY Subscribed to the Message with id=4 (room :: sails_model_message_4:create)
2015.07.06 16:05:29 SILLY Subscribed to the Message with id=5 (room :: sails_model_message_5:create)
2015.07.06 16:05:29 SILLY Subscribed to the Message with id=6 (room :: sails_model_message_6:create)
2015.07.06 16:05:29 SILLY Subscribed to the Message with id=7 (room :: sails_model_message_7:create)
```

But when create a new Message with owner=1, my subscriber socket does not receive the event.

Client code:

```
io.socket.get('/messages/get');
io.socket.on('message',function(obj){
    if(obj.verb === 'created'){
        $log.info(obj)
    }
});
```

Create code:

```
Message.create(data).exec(function(error, data){
    Message.publishCreate({id: data.id, owner: data.owner, message : data.message , type: data.type});
});
```

Or maybe watch is better? I could use watch but there I could not specify any criteria.
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/watch

Comment: Finally solved this, here is my answer on this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686502/sails-js-with-socket-io-how-to-subscribe-to-new-model-that-fits-criteria-durin/31256254